# Convert dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff from String to DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I am trying to convert
a string of the below format
dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff
into DateTime value

easiest way?

BTW

```
IFormatProvider culture = new CultureInfo("en-US", true);
DateTime.ParseExact(timeString, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff",culture);
```

Throws an invalid time exception

Eg.
11/12/2009 13:30:00.000
Where 12 is the month (i know weird)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to use **HH**

```
string timeString = "11/12/2009 13:30:00.000";
IFormatProvider culture = new CultureInfo("en-US", true); 
DateTime dateVal = DateTime.ParseExact(timeString, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff", culture);
```

Answer (score 4):

`hh:mm:ss.fff` should be `HH:mm:ss.fff` since you're using 24-hour format.